# Word for words that sound like the sound

Tags: single-word-requests

In our English lesson, we talked about words that are derived from sounds.

Our teacher said they are "anamatapic", but it seems I can't get the spelling right. Even google does not provide a good suggestion for a better spelling.

So now I am looking for the word that sounds like "anamatapic" and describes the professional term for words that sound like the sound. Everything's clear?

I have tried

- [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=anamapatic)

---

Close votes: thanks for the meta reference to good resources.

The following online resources don't help:

- [OED](http://public.oed.com/?post_type=page&s=anamatapic)
- [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english-german/?q=anamatapic)
- [The free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anamatapic)
- [Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=anamapatic&searchmode=nl)
- [Onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=anamapatic&ls=a)

These will guide to correct results:

- [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anamatapic?s=t)
- [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anamatapic)
- [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/all/?q=anamatapic)

So, yeah, maybe I could have found it there.

And if you [try Google now](https://www.google.de/search?q=anamatapic), you'll get a result from a strange website, which is not a dictionary, but some kind of Q&A style forum. Maybe we can put that one in the list of helpful resources, too :-D

Also cool: if I would have type [the title of this EL&U question into Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=Word%20for%20words%20that%20sound%20like%20the%20sound) instead of the intended word, the first hit is the correct Wikipedia article. I'll try to derive a pattern from this.

Comment: I guess you mean: onomatopoeic!

Comment: . . . or onomatopoetic.

Comment: Spelling tips the next time you need to remember! http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156522/mnemonic-for-onomatopoeia

Comment: Come on now, how can this possibly be general reference if he doesn't know what word to look up? Someone please give me the name of a commonly available reference that can be used to trivially answer this question.

Comment: I have just copied your question title in Google, and the first five or six results have websites that mention onomatopoeia. Sometimes, all you need is a good definition/description to find what you need.

Comment: Aha, I see we have arrived at the same conclusion. Jolly good :) @phenry see my comment. I swear I did nothing else but copied the OP's question.

Comment: The mods are in discussion about this question. We think that this is a useful question that could help other people find resources for words that they have heard, but are unsure of how to spell. With that regard, it might be a suitable candidate for the [English Language Learners site](http://ell.stackexchange.com), where a larger audience is more likely to be looking for this type of resource.

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56600/what-part-of-speech-are-non-human-interjections-like-oink-and-bang

Comment: Hmm, this site is for `Spelling` according to the tour, so it seems on topic. of course ELL is also on topic, because the source of the problem was an English class. Maybe as a non-native speaker i should prefer ELL in general. But honestly, the tour should point out that there are related sites - and not just "124 other SE places". I mean: a clear differentiation e.g. between EL&U and ELL. If questions can be asked in German on German language, even that would fit for me.

Comment: @ThomasW. This is something which was brought to the fore in the recent moderator election. This question, together with one or two other recent posts, is a good candidate to help with the mods' discussion which KitFox alluded to. What is absolutely clear is that saying this question might be suitable for ELL is not a reflection on your English or being a non-native speaker at all. It's simply debating where questions should go **to be of greatest use,** and what general guidance can be drawn up to assist with that decision.

Comment: I feel like adding that the elephant in the room is that it's the teacher's whole job to answer your questions, so you should just go ahead and ask him right then and there. Not sure why you chose to try and look it up in a dictionary instead, which of course is all but impossible. (That's what [reverse dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=word+that+imitates+a+sound) are there for.)

Comment: I agree with @phenry: if this is "general reference", then there's no reason for the Internet to exist, never mind this site. I mean, really: how and where do you look up a word if you don't know anything besides its meaning?

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I have only one lesson a week. I didn't ask the teacher for the spelling of the word, because usually I can figure it out without bothering him. This time I was not successful. Of course I could ask him during next lesson on 2nd of July.

Comment: FWIW, I vote for migrating this question to ELL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Onomatopoeia](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Onomatopeic): (noun), onomatopoeic ( adj) :

> The formation or use of words such as buzz or murmur that imitate the sounds associated with the objects or actions they refer to.